# Do high-profile journals edit authors’ figures?

Tags: publications, graphics

I have a paper published in a *Angewandte Chemie*, “one of the most renowned chemistry journals”, and realized that the figures have been edited from the version I had submitted. They did not tell us about it, but clearly modifications have been made for typographical consistence with their style guide: some symbols have been italicized, axes labels have been changed from, e.g., “Temperature (K)” into “Temperature / K”, etc.

I was surprised, because I know that [most journals don’t typically edit figures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/what-figure-formatting-can-should-or-will-be-done-by-a-publisher), so I wonder: is *Angewandte Chemie* unique in this respect? Do other higher-profile journals, such as *Nature* or *Science*, edit figures or provide feedback to authors on graphics?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of the one Daniel's pointing out, and therefore I'm voting to close.

Comment: Okay, I have tried to make it more different: the other questions asks about journals in general, and how you could ask *them* to help with figures. My question would be about how common it is for a specific subset (high-profile journals, of which no example was given in the answers to David’s question) to edit graphics or advise authors on the matter.

Comment: It still seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - It's a close call. The question isn't "does this happen?", but rather, "this happened, is this a one-off or a common thing I'm not familiar with?" It seems like a useful enough question to me to be worth a re-opening.

Comment: Didn't they show you a final proof copy?  Journals often at least edit the size/position of figures in my experience.  Some of them also reformat formulas and other aspects.  I recently had a journal article where they had to completely rebuild my tables to fit their in-house style.  I had to note a couple of issues, which they fixed.  Usually they give you a final proof so that you can check that your original intent is still retained.

Comment: @Namey yes, they gave notice, and all they did was fine… but I was surprised that they had reformatted the figures themselves, not only the captions/text

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess I wouldn't be that surprised if it happened.  While there is a trend toward things to be more camera-ready, it seems sensical that some major venues still like a high level of consistency among their figures.  I also get the feeling that journals who still put out a lot of paper copies take a lot more care with that sort of thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, high-profile journals do typically edit figures for style and consistency. You will find this information on their web sites, e.g. [nature physics](http://www.nature.com/nphys/authors/submit/index.html#Formats).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question; if anything, it suggests that Nature Physics *doesn't* edit figures, unless you specifically use Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: @eykanal They do edit figures. The statement can be found as the last sentence of the first paragraph (and elsewhere): "This allows us to restyle to our journal house style."

Comment: Good point, I missed that sentence.